# .net core azure pipeline deployment with editable folders

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nopcommerce

I have a .net core web app (NopCommerce 4.1) that I am attempting to setup a build and release pipeline for.

However, when I setup the pipeline my deployment is failing because it attempts to create a folder, but write rights do not exist. I have confirmed this with Kudu where I get an error message (409) when attempting to create a folder via the cmd shell.

NopCommerce requires a couple of folders to be editable, but azure pipelines deploys a zip folder and creates a folder structure that is read only.

I want to deploy to a dev, test, prod environment with a folder structure that is editable (as nopcommerce creates folders and writes files to them dynamically).

I followed the following YAML structure:
https://damianbrady.com.au/2018/10/11/what-yaml-do-i-need-for-azure-pipelines/

Is there a way to create a build / deployment that will deploy either:
1. The files without zipping
2. Transfer a zip, unpack into a folder structure with execute/modify/create permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.The files without zipping 2.Transfer a zip, unpack into a folder structure with execute/modify/create permissions

We could use the Azure kudu [Zip API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip) to do that.

**Note**:*It is not recommended for deployments Kudu's zip API.*

Kudu Rest API is an effective way to move multiple files to your site, but zipdeploy is preferable for deployment For more information please refer to this [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file#comparison-with-zip-api).

In your case, you could use a Powershell task with Powershell script to invoke Kudu Zip API to do that. For information about how invoke REST API with Powershell, please refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710299/kudu-rest-api-command-endpoint-error-when-executing-powershell/50711663#50711663).

Comment: Thanks for the solution Tom. I have found an alternative way that uses the old WYSIWYG pipeline editor that avoids the kudu API, but I've accepted your answer as it sounds like a viable alternative